# Investigating continuity of a function in metric spaces

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity

So I have a function $F: (\mathscr{C}[0,1],d_{\infty}) \rightarrow (\mathscr{l}^{\infty}, D)$
So it's a function that maps from metric space of uniformly continuous functions in [0,1] to a space of bounded sequence (the largest of them).

The function is defined as:
$$F(f)=\left(f(1),f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right),...\right)$$

Since it's a function between metric spaces i need to investigate it's continuity. I was thinking i should just bound my function with a ball, but i don't knwo how.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function $F$ is linear and that you have

$$ \Vert F(f) \Vert_{l^{\infty}} \leq \Vert f \Vert_{\sup}.$$

Thus, your function is continuous.